# Rank of bundle map of vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $\pi_L :L \rightarrow M$ be a smooth vector bundle.

Why is a rank of a smooth bundle map $a:L \rightarrow TM$ as a vector bundle a lower semi continuous function on $M$?

Is there any more general assertions?

Answer (score 1):

Take some $x \in M$. Picking local bases of $L$ and $TM$ in some neighborhood $U$ of $x$, it is possible to write $a$ as a matrix (with entries that depend on the point of $U$ you are taking). If the rank of $a$ at $x$ is $k$, that implies there's some $k \times k$ submatrix of the matrix for $a$ whose determinant is nonzero. By continuity of the entries, the determinant is still nonzero near $x$, so the rank of $a$ near $x$ is at least $k$ (it might be higher).

I'm not sure what a generalization would be. There's an entirely analogous result for ranks of smooth functions between manifolds, with a similar proof.

Comment: Thank you so much.Now that you've mentioned it,it is clear.